# How to validate XML against XSD 1.1 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xsd, xsd-validation

Is there a JavaScript library (or a Node package) capable of validating XML against **XSD 1.1**?

I have found a plenty of libraries, but none of them capable of dealing with XSD 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a satisfying answer, but unfortunately, no, there are no JavaScript XSD 1.1 validators.  There are also no Python or C# XSD 1.1 validators either.  For XSD 1.0 in JavaScript, see [**xml.js**](https://github.com/kripken/xml.js).

### XSD 1.1 Validators

- [Xerces-J with PsychoPath XPath 2.0](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-2) (Java)
- [Saxon EE](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html) (Java)
- [Altova](http://www.altova.com/whatsnew_missionkit.html) (I do not believe their library is released for use outside of their product, though.)

**So, in JavaScript, your options for validating XML against XSD 1.1 would include:**

- Make an AJAX call out to a server running one of the Java-based XSD
  1.1 validators.
- Extend xml.js to support XSD 1.1 (a non-trivial task) or
  write your own XSD 1.1 validator in JavaScript (definitely a
  non-trivial task).
- Port the Xerces-J XSD 1.1 validator, possibly with the help of [Google Web
  Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/), to JavaScript.